# How to give color to a particular word in docx

Tags: python, arrays, string, sorting, docx

I have seen many code like this:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
document = Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run('some text')
font = run.font
font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x42, 0x24, 0xE9)
p=document.add_paragraph('aaa')
document.save('demo1.docx')
```

but above code applies a color to all sentences but i want a specific color to a specific word. how to achieve it ?

for example:

```
sentence = [' I want a color for a particular word in this sentence not to this whole 
            sentence']
selected_words = ['want', 'particular', 'this'] #<----- any color to this words from 
                                                #        above sentence!
```

i didnt find any code for my query or else i may put some of my tried code.
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split and join again. I am slightly modifying your example:

```
sentence = 'I want a color for a particular word in this sentence not to this whole sentence'
selected_words = ['want', 'particular', 'this']

from docx import Document
from docx.shared import RGBColor
document = Document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
sentence_split = sentence.split()
for x in sentence_split:
  if x in selected_words:
    run2 = paragraph.add_run(x)
    red = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
    run2.font.color.rgb = red
  else:
    paragraph.add_run(x)
  
  paragraph.add_run(" ")
```